# Запись значении нескольких combobox в файл

Tags: c#

Добрый день. Пробую написать программу, которая бы сохраняла данные из двух combobox и одного textbox в один файл. 
Вроде то, что я написал работает. Но нужна консультация, правильно ли я поступаю с точки зрения адекватности кода или можно как то иначе сделать запись.
Вот мой код:

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
        saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Текстовый документ (*.txt)|*.txt|Все файлы (*.*)|*.*";

        if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(saveFileDialog1.FileName);
            streamWriter.WriteLine(cbFIO.Text);
            streamWriter.WriteLine(cbDate.Text);
            streamWriter.WriteLine(tbRandomText.Text);
            streamWriter.Close();
        }
    }
```

И еще хотелось бы узнать, можно ли сделать запись в файл таким образом, что бы данные combobox в файл записывались через двоеточие в одну строку?
К примеру в первом combobox у меня ФИО а второй combobox содержит дату рождения.
При записи в файл хотелось бы получить запись в файле вида
"Петров Иван Сергеевич : 07.12.87"
Мой вариант кода сохраняет построчно.

Comment: А зачем вы пишите *WriteLine* - используйте *Write*. Добавьте точку-с-запятой так: `Write(";")`. А если код вам в итоге покажется сильно громоздким почитайте про `string.Format` в нете много примеров

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> И еще хотелось бы узнать, можно ли сделать запись в файл таким образом, что бы данные combobox в файл записывались через двоеточие в одну строку?

Можно так:

```
streamWriter.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} : {1}", cbFIO.Text, cbDate.Text));
```

В остальном все ок, КМК.

Answer (score 1):

Если ты хочешь сохранить состояние программы, то для этих целей лучше использовать сериализацию.

Если таких значений немного, то можно выполнять сохранение непосредственно в AppConfig.

```
  private void UpdateConfig(string key, string value, string fileName)
    {
        var configFile = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(fileName);
        configFile.AppSettings.Settings[key].Value = value;

        configFile.Save();
    }
```